# How to create Mac OS X global hot key to open .txt file in MacVim.app at vim 'mark'?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, shortcut-menu, macvim

Can and how can I create Mac OS X global hot key (possibly mapped to an OS X service, like what OmniFocus and Fantastical offer to make new entries in their inbox/calendar, respectively) to open a specific .txt file in MacVim.app at a specific [vim mark](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks)?

I suspect I can use Automator/AppleScript or some such in combination with vim's "global" marks to accomplish this, but uncertain.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities are [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/). Keyboard Maestro will set a global keyboard shortcut.

I assume there is a command-line utility for MacVim like there is for BBEdit and if it can open at a specific ‘vim mark’. For example, BBEdit’s command is called `bbedit` and cal open a specific line number using “:xy” where “xy” is the line number. You could make a Keyboard Maestro shortcut that will open a specific file using this command

```
/usr/local/bin/bbedit /path/to/filename:33
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting one :) and I figured it out!

The solution is based on 3 steps (you could do it on 2 as well):

1. Create a shell script that open up the desired textfile on a specific vim mark
2. Create a Automator workflow to run this script
3. Add a shortcut to the workflow

Here we go:

#### 1. Shellscript to open textfile on a specific vim mark: launchlog.sh

```
# $HOME/bin/launchlog.sh
# This will open $HOME/test.txt on vim mark b
/Applications/mvim -c "execute 'normal! \`b'" $HOME/test.txt
```

#### 2. Create an Automator workflow

*There are plenty tutorial around how to make Automator workflows. Stick to the one the describe it best for you.*

You need to create a workflow that executes a shell script. There you paste the path to your script. My workflow is called openJournal.workflow

[image: Automator workflow to run a shellscript (german version)]

As a hint: The workflows are stored under `$HOME/Library/Services`

#### 3. Assign a shortcut to the workflow

This can be done under *Systempreferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts*. Under section *Services* you can assign your just created workflow a keyboard shortcut. In my example I added the `Shift + Ctrl + J`as shortcut. 
[image: Add keyboard shortcut to workflow]

Now you can open your specific text file on the specific vim mark (in my example the vim mark `b`) by hitting `Shift + Ctrl + J`on your keyboard.

*As a matter of course, this works only if you have a vim mark b set on your textfile.*

#### Do it in 2 steps

You could put the content of the shell script into the Automator workflow.

So you would skip the creation of the shell script itself. But this comes with the disadvantage, that you have to change the automator workflow if you want another behaviour. I myself like the flexibilty to just change the shell script and have the desired behaviour.

Hope that helps.